# Not able to start Ignite Visor

Tags: java, ignite

I'm trying to run Ignite Visor locally.

I have already 1 client and 2 servers running, and when I'm trying to start `ignitevisorcmd.sh` script I'm getting following error:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128M; support was removed in 8.0
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole

I started using Ignite version 2.1.0 RELEASE and I'm running this script directly from `apache-ignite-2.1.0-src/bin` folder.

Comment: The error indocates a classpath problem.Try running the command from the directory above -  `bin/ignitevisorcmd.sh`

Comment: @DaveH, I changed the path, unfortunately still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running it from your project:

- Make sure you have `ignite-visor-console` as a dependency in your `pom.xml`

If you are running it from Apache Ignite distribution directory:

- Make sure you've downloaded a binary distribution, not a source package (ending in -src). Source build will be required to be built first before you can run anything. Try `mvn clean install` for that or just download binaries instead of sources.

You will also need to pass XML configuration to visor console if it's not in Ignite directory.

Comment: I was running from distribution directory, but from Release version(source).  I switched to binary and now everything works correctly, thanks!